# Rails inflector inconsistent behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm using Rails 4.1.1 and Mongoid 4.0.0.beta1.
I have the following in my inflections.rb,

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w( hvac )
end
```

I have an hvac model.
Sometimes, the Mongoid query will look for the collection hvacs then out of the blue the same query will correctly use hvac.   I am at a loss to try to figure out why sometimes it correctly does not add an "s" on the end other times it does.   Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You're sure it's random and there's no way to reproduce this error?

Comment: I have not figured out a way to reproduce.  I didn't mention that the #pluralize and #singularize string methods work correctly in a Rails console no matter what the queries are doing.   It appears to only change after restarting the server, maybe it's the way I'm holding my mouth!

Comment: It's pretty consistent right now that 'hvac'.pluralize method correctly returns 'hvac' but queries on the Hvac model look for the 'hvacs' collection.   Could this just be an irregularity for the string 'hvac'?  (it's an acronym), I'm about ready to just give up and use the default behaviour.

Comment: Maybe it is Mongoid bug that it doesn't follow user-defined inflections sometimes? I don't use mongoid on daily basis so not gonna dig into code, maybe you want to (be warned however that it's ugly/complicated as hell)